# Why is my shared_ptr leaking memory?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, sdl

I am trying to use C++11's std::tr1::shared_ptr to manage SDL_Surface pointers. Note, I am not using Boost. I have defined a deleter for the shared_ptr to use SDL_FreeSurface.

Declared like:

```
class Engine {
private:
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> _scr;
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> _bg;
```

Defined (in Engine's ctor) like:

```
_scr = std::tr1::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>( SDL_SetVideoMode(Data::SCR_WIDTH,
                                                          Data::SCR_HEIGHT,
                                                        32, SDL_SWSURFACE),
                                            SurfaceDeleter<SDL_Surface>());

  _bg = std::tr1::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>(IMG_Load(Data::IM_BACKGROUND),
                                         SurfaceDeleter<SDL_Surface>());
```

The custom deleter:

```
template<typename T>
class SurfaceDeleter{ 
public:
  void operator() (T*& d) const {
    if(d){
      SDL_FreeSurface(d);
    }
  }
};
```

The only object holding the shared_ptr is the Engine. The shared_ptr was used like so:

```
  SDL_BlitSurface(_bg.get(), nullptr, _scr.get(), nullptr);
  SDL_Flip(_scr.get());
```

Valgrind results:

```
==3648== 8 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 16 of 292
==3648==    at 0x402A018: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3648==    by 0x431FBE0: strdup (in /lib/libc-2.14.1.so)

==3648== 1 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 292
==3648==    at 0x402A018: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3648==    by 0x494A590: _XlcDefaultMapModifiers (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3648==    by 0x494A99A: XSetLocaleModifiers (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3648==    by 0x4097CDB: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3)
==3648==    by 0x4083868: SDL_VideoInit (in /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3)
==3648==    by 0x40594D9: SDL_InitSubSystem (in /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3)
==3648==    by 0x42C3212: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.14.1.so)

==3648== 980 (68 direct, 912 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 258 of 292
==3648==    at 0x402A102: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==3648==    by 0x49402A6: ??? (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3648==    by 0x49407A2: ??? (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3648==    by 0x494212F: ??? (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3648==    by 0x49429BA: _XlcCreateLC (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3648==    by 0x4965957: _XlcUtf8Loader (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3648==    by 0x494A793: _XOpenLC (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3648==    by 0x494A8F1: _XlcCurrentLC (in /usr/lib/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==3648==    by 0x4097CDB: ??? (in /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3)
==3648==    by 0x4083868: SDL_VideoInit (in /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3)
==3648==    by 0x40594D9: SDL_InitSubSystem (in /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0.11.3)
==3648==    by 0x42C3212: (below main) (in /lib/libc-2.14.1.so)
```

Comment: Do not call `SDL_FreeSurface` on the pointer returned by `SDL_SetVideoMode`.  It is released when you call `SDL_Quit`.  See [the docs](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_SetVideoMode) under "Return Value".

Comment: I tried removing the deleter from the _scr shared_ptr but the leak still exists.

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to go on. We would need to see how you *use* the shared pointers. What objects hold them, what objects govern *them*, etc. Also, there's no such thing as `std::tr1::shared_ptr` in C++11; it's just `std::shared_ptr`; TR1 predates C++11 and shouldn't be used if you're using C++11.

Comment: @Google: I wasn't attempting to answer your question about the memory leak.  I was just informing you that your deleter is not valid in that case.  Also, if you removed the deleter, that means it will use the default deleter, which essentially just calls `delete` on the pointer, which also should not be done.

Comment: The shared pointer in C++11 is just `std::shared_ptr`, not `std::tr1::shared_ptr`

Comment: I fixed that thanks, I added more about the usage-- I only blitted the background on the screen and flipped the screen. That was it.

Comment: Try supplying --leak-check=full as an argument to valerind, that will give you stack traces of where the leaked memory was allocated.  Also make sure your program exits normally from main(), not by calling exit() or ctrl-c, etc.  Lastly, don't worry about the "possibly lost" items, only the "definitely lost" ones.

Comment: I checked and they seem to all be similar to the new valgrind results I posted-- none refer to SDL_FreeSurface.

Comment: Are you, in fact, calling `SDL_Quit` prior to exiting? (or as an `atexit` call)

Comment: It's being called before returning EXIT_SUCCESS from main.

Comment: the purpose of a `shared_ptr` is to provide reference counting on its object pointer. Using `shared_ptr` as you have shown would make sense if you are passing the `_bg` and `_scr` variables around to other `shared_ptr<SDL_Surface>` instances, or copy-constructing multiple `Engine` instances from each other. Are you doing any of that? As @NicolBolas said, there is not enough information to go on.

Comment: Are you sure these are leaks of the shared pointers? I'm no valgrind or SDL expert, but the stack traces in the valgrind output don't seem to point to the functions that are initializing the shared pointers. Specifically, I don't see `SDL_SetVideoMode()`, `IMG_Load()` or the `Engine` ctor in the stack traces.

Comment: Sorry everyone-- it appears the shared_ptrs are working just fine-- there seems to be a problem with SDL. I tested some simple examples and all are leaking memory. If I find out what is causing this I will post a solution.

Comment: @Google - it's possibly actually your video driver that's at fault here

Comment: Valgrind is likely to give some false positives for data that is leaked because it is still allocated at the time the application exits, but it is only allocated once and never grows. If you look at the number of actual bytes (989 bytes) it's not nearly enough to be a surface, or any important data structure. It's likely some internal SDL state variables

Answer (score 3):

Run valgrind with `--track-origins=yes` so it shows you where the leaked memory was allocated.

You might also want to use `--leak-check=full` and `--leak-resolution=high` (although the latter should be the default)